# Moving along Bezier Curve in processing

Tags: processing

My code for `the ball moving in a Bezier Curve from start to the middle of the curve` is:

```
     void ballMove()
    {

      if(y[0]==height*1/10)
      {

        bezier (x[0], y[0],x[1], y[1], x[2], y[2], x[3], y[3]);
      float x0; float x1; float x2; float x3; 
    float y0; float y1; float y2; float y3;

    x0 = x[0]; x1 = x[1]; x2 = x[2]; x3 = x[3]; 
    y0 = y[0]; y1 = y[1]; y2 = y[2]; y3 = y[3];


     float t =  (frameCount/100.0)%1;
      float x = bezierPoint(x0, x1, x2, x3, t);
      float y = bezierPoint( y0, y1, y2, y3, t);

       if(t>=0.5)
      {
        t=0;
      }

      while(t==0.5)
     {
       a=x;
       b=y;
     }
      while(t>0.5)
      {
        ellipse(a,b,30,30);
      }
      fill(255,0,0);
      if(t!=0)
      {
      ellipse(x, y, 15, 15);
      }
      }
    }
```

I have defined everything in setup, draw etc, but i want to launch the ball from the start to the middle of the Bezier Curve only one time whenever space is pressed.

The current version shows me the loop. How can i do that?

Tried Everything like return, break, changing the t parameter etc, but the code doesn't work. I'm new in processing.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of a disconnected method?

Answer (score 0):

Biggest mistake that you make is altering value of `t` after you calculated `x` and `y` positions of red ball. To avoid this you need first calculate `t` between [0, 1] in you case [0, 0.5] and then alter this value according to state of your program.

Second mistake you made while calculating `t` from `frameCount`. First you use modulo to extract numbers [0, 50] and then map it in range [0, 0.5] like this

```java
float t =  (frameCount % 50) * 0.01;
```

You also mentioned that you want to repeat this animation after pressing some key. For this you will need `keyPressed` method and some  global variables to represent state of program and store starting frame of animation (because `frameCount` should be read only). So basic functionality can be achieved like this:

```java
boolean run = false;
float f_start = 0;

void ballMove() {
  noFill();
  bezier (x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);

  float t =  ((frameCount - f_start) % 50) * 0.01;

  if (run == false) {
    t = 0;
  }
  float x = bezierPoint(x0, x1, x2, x3, t);
  float y = bezierPoint( y0, y1, y2, y3, t);

  fill(255, 0, 0);
  ellipse(x, y, 5, 5);
}

void keyPressed() {
  run = !run;
  f_start = frameCount;
}
```

Hope this will help you. Next time pls post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we do not need to fight with your code.